# NHibernate Fluent group by

Tags: nhibernate, group-by

I have this nhibernate criteria:

```
       criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", DetachedCriteria.For<ReconItemReconSide>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("ReconItemFk"))
            .Add(Projections.Min("ReconciliationSideFk")))
            .Add(Expression.In(Projections.Property("ReconItemFk"), items))
            ));
```

-which becomes this query (I have removed some of the fields from the outer select to minimize the length here):

```
SELECT this_.Id                        as Id8_0_
FROM   CI.BM_RECONCILIATION_SIDE this_
WHERE  this_.Id in (SELECT   this_0_.BM_RECON_ITEM               as y0_,
                         min(this_0_.BM_RECONCILIATION_SIDE) as y1_
                FROM     CI.BM_RECON_ITEM_RECON_SIDE this_0_
                WHERE    this_0_.BM_RECON_ITEM in (345061 /* :p0 */,345877 /* :p1 */)
                GROUP BY this_0_.BM_RECON_ITEM)
```

The problem is that I want the inner-select to select one field only (min(this_0_.BM_RECONCILIATION_SIDE)), but the groupby also add the groupby-field to the select.

I want to be able to create a groupby without having to project the groupby field itself. 
The query should look similar to this:

```
SELECT this_.Id                        as Id8_0_
FROM   CI.BM_RECONCILIATION_SIDE this_
WHERE  this_.Id in (SELECT   
                         min(this_0_.BM_RECONCILIATION_SIDE) as y1_
                FROM     CI.BM_RECON_ITEM_RECON_SIDE this_0_
                WHERE    this_0_.BM_RECON_ITEM in (345061 /* :p0 */,345877 /* :p1 */)
                GROUP BY this_0_.BM_RECON_ITEM)
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it seems like this is still an [open issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1426) with nHib.
like they always say- you're welcome to implement it yourself.. :)

Comment: Thanks - it doesn't get me anywhere closer to a solution, but it does show that i am not the only one with this issue.